# Fancy header won't align left and isn't full width while using res.cls

Tags: fancyhdr, resume, cv

I want to align my fancy header with my section headings, but can't currently. In pic1.png I'm trying to get Washington, DC to align to the left with the Experience section. 
[image: pic1.png]

I am trying to same thing with footer, can't post picture example due to low rep :/

I've tried adjusting \oddsidemargin and \hoffset and don't quite know how to use the geometry package to try and troubleshoot this.

I belive this is due to the res.cls found at https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/ which automatically indents a margin somehow. Help on this would be really appreciated as I am very new to Latex.

Compilable CV attached below:

```
\documentclass[overlapped]{res} %can use [margin] or [line] or [centered]
%overlapped instead of margin, trying to left justify fancy header

%%%%%%%%%%%% Info %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Build with PDFLatex
% Texmaker used
% See 'packages used'
% class: res.cls 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% change main bullet style to small clear circles
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\circ$}

% packages used
%\usepackage{geometry} %can't seem to solve issue with geometry
%\oddsidemargin = 0in %doesn't force header left
%\hoffset = 0in % just shifts all of it left

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{hyperref} %linking profile information, last package imported
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan, %this will color my external web links
} %from ShareLatex

\fancyhead{
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X[l] X[c] X[r]}
    \faMapMarker \hspace{1pt} Washington, DC &
    \begin{LARGE} \textbf{Ronald Clinton} \end{LARGE} & 
    \faMobile \hspace{1pt} (123) 456-7890\\
    \end{tabu}
    }

%make footer of contact information, use with fancyhrd
\fancyfoot{
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X[l] X[c] X[r]}
    \Large{\faLinkedin} &
    \Large{\faEnvelopeO \hspace{1pt}     \normalsize{myemail}} & 
    \Large{\faGithub} \\ \\
     & \textsc{Please fix header/footer width} & %make this grey
    \end{tabu}
    }

\pagestyle{fancy}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Uncomment \Large... for normal heading
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\Large{\name{Bill Reagan}}
%this is a standard title

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}    

\begin{resume}
\hspace{6pt}

\section{\large{Experience}} \textbf{Company} \hfill Start\textit{ - present} \\      \textsc{Role1, \\ Role2}
\begin{itemize} \itemsep=-2pt
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\item item 4
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Company} \hfill Start - End \\ \textsc{Role}
\begin{itemize} \itemsep=-2pt
\item item1 
\end{itemize}


\section{\large{Education}}
\textbf{Online Degree}  \hfill Start - \textit{present} \\ \textsc{Degree Name}
\begin{itemize} \itemsep=-2pt
\item item 1
\begin{itemize} \itemsep=-2pt
\item subitem 1
\item subitem 2
\item subitem 3
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute} \\
\textsc{Major, Minor}\\
extracurriculars of note

\section{\large{Projects}}
\textbf{Project 1}
\begin{itemize} \itemsep=-2pt
\item item 1
\end{itemize}
\textbf{Project 2}
\begin{itemize}
\item item1 
\end{itemize}

\section{\large{Skills}}
%change to Technical Skills if using \documentclass[margin]{res}

\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X[c] X[c] X[c]}
 \underline{\faStarO \faStarO \faStarO} & \underline{\faStarO \faStarO} &     \underline{\faStarO} \vspace{0.1in} \\
 This & may & not \\
 look & appealing & but \\
 it &  was & fun \\
 to & use & \LaTeX \\
\end{tabu}

\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not the other packages, but the `res` class that is the problem. But there's an easy enough fix: `\newsectionwidth{0in}` (check with `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}`). Note, however, that you are using `\Large` and `\large` wrongly in every instance. It is a declaration or switch, not a command that takes an argument. (So `{\large <text>}` not `\large{<text>}`. And never use it inside a command like `\section`: you should define `\section` to do what you want it to do.

Comment: I'd also add: 'CV' classes are notoriously inflexible and not always well written, so consider carefully whether you need it. As you are probably already overwriting a major feature of the class with your `tabu`-in-`fancyhdr` (and `tabu` is also a dangerous package to use), I'm not convinced you're getting that much use out of the `res` class file.

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of `\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X[l] X[c] X[r]}`, you should write `\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {@{}X[l] X[c] X[r]@{}}`.

Comment: The class is considered obsolete and should not  be used anymore.

Comment: @jon thank you for the \usepackage[showframe] tip, that helped a ton. Your solution worked and based on yours and others' comments I've decided **to create my own class** rather than hack my way to a poor solution with res

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments.